# preg_match all words start with an @?

Tags: php, regex

i'm not very firm with regular Expressions, so i have to ask you:

How to find out with PHP if a string contains a word starting with @ ??

e.g. i have a string like "This is for @codeworxx" ???

I'm so sorry, but i have NO starting point for that :(

Hope you can help.

Thanks,
Sascha

---

okay thanks for the results - but i did a mistake - how to implement in eregi_replace ???

```
$text = eregi_replace('/\B@[^\B]+/','<a href="\\1">\\1</a>', $text);
```

does not work??!?

why? do i not have to enter the same expression as pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Match anything with has some whitespace in front of a `@` followed by something else than whitespace:

```
$ cat 1812901.php

<?php
    echo preg_match("/\B@[^\B]+/", "This should @match it");
    echo preg_match("/\B@[^\B]+/", "This should not@ match");
    echo preg_match("/\B@[^\B]+/", "This should match nothing and return 0");
    echo "\n";
?>

$ php 1812901.php 
100
```

Comment: You should change the _*_ to _+_, so it won't catch empty words

Comment: Also depends on what is a word, you might want to use `\w` instead of `[^\B]`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you define a word a sequence of letters with no white spaces between them, then this should be a good starting point for you:

```
$subject = "This is for @codeworxx";
$pattern = '/\s*@(.+?)\s/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Explanation:
`\s*@(.+?)\s` - look for anything starting with **@**, group all the following letters, numbers, and anything which is not a whitespace (space, tab, newline), till the closest whitespace.

See the output of the `$matches` array for accessing the inner groups and the regex results.

Comment: Acutally that doesn't match something **starting** with @, it catches xxx@yyy.com too.

Comment: I fixed it, should work now. You can also use @MYYN's solution

Answer (score 1):

break your string up like this:

```
$string = 'simple sentence with five words';
$words = explode(' ', $string );
```

Then you can loop trough the array and check if the first character of each word equals "@":

```
if ($stringInTheArray[0] == "@")
```

Comment: This is actually a bad way of doing it. It's costly for nothing. Regular expressions have been created in such task in mind.

Comment: what is bad and what is bad? is not up to you to decide. this is a perfectly normal and legible way to do what OP wants, without cluttering your code with regex.

Comment: @levislevis85. Relatively speaking, keeping performance and manageability in mind, a simple regular expression *is* usually preferable to manual string manipulation, especially on large strings, even though it is a little harder to learn... And how is cluttering your code up with string manipulation code any better than cluttering it up with regexp? At least they are generally pretty short ;-)

Comment: @Atli, because with regex, you are just like reading an essay that is encoded in numbers. Too much of it makes your code hard to read. Not every solution need a regex.

Answer (score 0):

@OP, no need regex. Just PHP string methods

```
$mystr='This is for @codeworxx';
$str = explode(" ",$mystr);
foreach($str as $k=>$word){
    if(substr($word,0,1)=="@"){
        print $word;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would probably be better just to split the string on the @ char, and make sure it is preceded with a white-space and followed by a valid character.

Comment: down voted because I didn't use regex? What a ridiculous joke!

Comment: @Atli, if i want, i can trim the variables to get the results.

Answer (score 0):

Just incase this is helpful to someone in the future

```
/((?<!\S)@\w+(?!\S))/
```

This will match any word containing alphanumeric characters, starting with "@." It will not match words with "@" anywhere but the start of the word.

Matching cases:

```
@username
foo @username bar
foo @username1 bar @username2
```

Failing cases:

```
foo@username
@username$
@@username
```