# Twitter handle regular expression PHP

Tags: php, regex, expression

I need a regular expression to grab @twitterUser from some text. I don't want it to grab emails like example@gmail.com I have a regular expression I'm using that takes care of that, my only issue is I'm grabbing a whole bunch of whitespace in the process, I need to improve the expression so that I don't collect all that white space, but still keep it from grabbing emails or anything that has a character before an @ symbol. Here's what I got:

```
/(?:[^\w]@([\w]+)([^.\s]+))/igm
```

positive look behind seems like it would work, but not supported in javascript. Any ideas?

Comment: Show some examples of what you are matching and what you don't want to match. You can only match 1 whitespace with this part `[^\w]` You could use an assertion `(?<!\w)` instead.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812883/preg-match-all-words-start-with-an